# Angular-ui-router causing infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to learn angular with this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/wiring-everything-up and I've hit a snag where opening the application runs into an infinite loop of calling the /posts url. I've checked my routes with postman and they are working as intended so I'm not sure why this isn't resolving correctly. Below is the 'posts' service, 'mainCtrl' controller, and the config. Could someone take a look and tell me if they see my error or if I need provide more of the code to help. Thank you.

Service

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
var o = {
    posts:[]
}

o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };

return o;

}])
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){
$scope.test = 'Hello world!';

$scope.posts = posts.posts;

$scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0,
      comments: [
        {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
        {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
      ]
    });
    $scope.title='';
    $scope.link='';
}

$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
  post.upvotes += 1;
};

}]);
```

Config

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'/home.html',
        controller:'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })
    .state('posts', {
        url:'/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl:'/posts.html',
        controller:'PostsCtrl'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I checked this but it didn't resolve the infinite loop problem I'm having

Comment: Try 'return angular.copy(data, o.posts);'

Comment: Sorry, that did not fix it either. This is the repository if you'd like to look deeper at it
https://github.com/RawleJuglal/rawle_news_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this question with a solution that partially has worked for me. I say partially because I'm no longer experience an infinite loop but if someone comes across this question doing the tutorial they will eventually run into a new problem where clicking submit does create a new post but the data is not there. Upon a refresh you will get the result you are looking for, but I have not solved this new issue.

The solution to the infinite loop is to use this in the service function

```
return $http.get('/posts').then(function(data){
        angular.copy(data.data, o.posts);
    });
```

The success syntax the the tutorial calls for does not work.